# How to isolate an element using DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to isolate the order total on this page:
https://www.brawtaliving.com/checkout/order-received/3014/?key=wc_order_zzPLbJK6Tnsjy

I've been able to narrow down to an HTMLCollection that contains the order total's figure using:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-Price-amount amount'))
```

But how can I narrow down to just showing $78,334.00?

This is the HTMLCollection I get - the price is in the first one:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">…</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">…</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">…</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">…</span>
```

Comment: Show sample of the basic html in the question. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go to some other website to sift though a whole ecommerce page to figure out what you are trying to accomplish, See [mcve]. In addition over time that link may rot, making this question useless in the future

Comment: [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Finding_the_first_element_matching_a_class) is much more flexible you should probably use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `[0].textContent` to the end:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-Price-amount amount')[0].textContent);
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>78,334.00</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ref JQuery `text()` for more details, This solution works for me

```js
console.log($('li.total .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <li class="total">
        Total:
        <strong>
          <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>78,334.00
          </span>
        </strong>
      </li>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()` function if you are using jquery.It returns all the text within the selected tag.Hope it helps

```js
var total = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text()
console.log(total)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>78,334.00</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Jack Bashford's answer is correct for your question. I provide a solution similar to his, but with a broader usage:

```js
// if you want the first - @Jack Bashford's solution
console.log('By Jack Bashford:');
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-Price-amount amount')[0].textContent);

// if you would like to have more freedom to process the selected collection
console.log('By Gergely Muka:');
[...document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-Price-amount amount')].forEach(
  (element, index, array) => {
    console.log(element.textContent)
  }
);
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">1</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">2</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">3</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" onclick="window.location='undefined'" style="cursor: pointer;">4</span>
```

You may need a transpiler for my solution to be able to use it on older browsers.